# Tag name not viewable when doing search on superuser

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

When doing a term search on superuser.com and it switches the term to a tag. If the tag is a tag you are following, you can't read the tag text unless you hover over the tag. The tag get places under the heading "within these tags" at the top right of the page. The text color and the background are the same color making it impossible to read the tag text unless you hover over the tag block.

Browser is Google Chrome on XP (not sure if it matters as I haven't tested it out with other browsers)

Comment: Fixed for me on Safari 4

Answer (score 3):

Here's a screenshot when searching with the [iphone] tag, which I'm following. (Firefox 3.5.2)

[image]

Comment: You searched for an error, you got an error.

Answer (score 2):

An example can be seen by going to this search results [page](https://superuser.com/search?q=windows+downloading+updates). I observe the same behavior as the OP using Chrome 2.0.172.39 on Windows XP.

Additional note, this seems to only affect a link to a tag that I have followed. Also, when following the link in IE 8.0.6001.18702, I do then see the documented issue.

Comment: Didn't notice that, but yes. Only seems to be present for tags being followed. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me on FireFox 3.0.14 on Linux [see my dupe question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22325/tag-display-bug-on-superuser).